# How to download Apache Zeppelin 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: apache, apache-zeppelin, helium

i want to install Apache Zeppelin 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT but cannot seem to find the proper link. I tried using https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/quickstart/install.html#downloading-binary-package but when i go to the "download page", it only has Zeppelin 0.7.3 files. Please guide me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll ending building it from source. It's the only way that I found: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/setup/basics/how_to_build.html

Or wait until it be ready to be released =(